# Hibernate - Saving children of the Nested Relationships

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the entities in the following manner

----------------------------------------------------Entity A--------------------------------------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    //bi-directional one-to-many association to B
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "a", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();


    public void add_B(B b) {
        this.b.add(b);
        b.setA(this);
    }

}
```

------------------------------------Entity B-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } )
    @JoinColumn( name = "A_ID" )
    private A a;

    //bi-directional one-to-many association to C
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "b", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private List<C> c = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add_C(C c) {
        this.c.add(c);
        c.setB(this);
    }

}
```

-------------------------------------Entity C-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL } )
    @JoinColumn( name = "B_ID" )
    private B b;

}
```

-----------------------------Mapper for A-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@Mapper(
        componentModel = "spring",
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN
)
public abstract class A_Mapper {

    public abstract A toEntity(DTO_A dto_a);

    @AfterMapping
    public void mapToEntity(@MappingTarget A a)
    {
        
        List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>(a.getB());
        for (B b: bs) { 
            a.add_B(b);

            for (C c:
                    b.getC() {
                b.add_C(c);
            }
        }
}
```

**After saving the entity A, the id of A should be set to B items and, id of B should be set to C. But a *"NullPointer Exception"* is thrown. Can someone show me how to fix that please. And how to modify the code such that ids of  both A and B will be set to C ? Thanks in advance**

Comment: *But a "NullPointer Exception" is thrown*. Where exactly. Add the stack trace